# XML XPath Question

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

My XML File looks like what is below, I am trying in my C Sharp code to have it only populate the combobox with questions based off of the name the course name that is selected. So for example if they select XML Programming in the course combobox, it will only display the questions for XML Programming in the question combobox. What would my XPath need to look like in order to accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated.

```
if (comboBoxCourse.SelectedItem.ToString() == selectNode.InnerText )
{
    try
    {
        XmlNodeList loadQuestions = loadDoc.SelectNodes("//Course/Questions");

        foreach (XmlNode xml in loadQuestions)
        {
            if (comboBoxCourse.SelectedItem.ToString() == selectNode.InnerText)
                comboBoxQuestions.Items.Add(xml.InnerText);
            else
                continue;
        }
    }

    catch (XmlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Courses>
    <Course>
        <Name>Direct X Programming</Name>
        <Professor>Michael Feeney</Professor>
        <Questions>Are you a Ninja</Questions>
        <Questions>What version of Direct X do we use?</Questions>
    </Course>
    <Course>
        <Name>XML Programming</Name>
        <Professor>Michael Feeney</Professor>
        <Questions>Are you an XML Ninja?</Questions>
        <Questions>What does XML stand for?</Questions>
    </Course>
    <Course>
        <Name>Windows GUI</Name>
        <Professor>Leanne Wong</Professor>
        <Questions>What is a treeview?</Questions>
        <Questions>What is a database?</Questions>
    </Course>
</Courses>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short one-liner XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted nodes.

Comment: Whichever answer you go with, you can use `System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to make sure you don't accidentally break your xpath if a course name has an apostrophe in it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use LINQ to XML instead:

```
doc.Root.Elements()
   .Where(c => c.Element("Name").Value == "Windows GUI")
   .Elements("Questions")
```

But if you really want to use XPath, it would look something like this:

```xml
/Courses/Course[Name = 'Windows GUI']/Questions
```

Be careful when constructing the query though, because you have to do some escaping of the string from the user.

Answer (score 1):

This will select and display in the output window all the questions associated with the selected course:

```
string xpath = string.Format("//Course[Name = '{0}']/Questions", comboBoxCourse.SelectedItem);
foreach (XmlNode node in loadDoc.SelectNodes(xpath))
      Debug.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
```

To load another combobox from those results I'd replace your entire method with this:

```
string xpath = string.Format("//Course[Name = '{0}']/Questions", comboBoxCourse.SelectedItem);
foreach (XmlNode node in loadDoc.SelectNodes(xpath))
      comboBoxQuestions.Items.Add(xml.InnerText);
```

Comment: What line in my code would I replace this one with?    xpath = string.Format("//Course[Name = '{0}']/Questions", comboBoxCourse.SelectedItem);

Comment: see edit. the second code snippet is what I think you are after

Comment: The xpath query works in the one program I have that checks xpath, but in my code it's still selecting more than the right number of questions. Since XML Programming is the 2nd one in the list, it selects the questions for Direct X Programming (being the 1st node) then selects the questions for xml programming as well and puts them in the combo box. Any ideas?

Comment: Should work as is. Make sure you're clearing the questions combo before each time you load it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I managed to figure it out with another way as well, I loaded the xml document again in my try statement

Answer (score 1):

**Use this XPath expression**:

```
/*/*[Name = 'XML Programming']/Questions
```

This selects any `Questions` element that is a child of any element that is a child of the top element and that has a child named `Name` whose string value is `'XML Programming'`